# Spring jms separator by correlationId for IBM mq

Tags: jms, listener, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I was able to browse through using [JmsPutGet](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-samples/master/gettingStarted/jms/JmsPutGet.java) with below browse selector for my IBM mq messages.

context.createBrowser(context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME), "JMSCorrelationID='ID:c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040'")

I am trying to do the same using spring jms using JmsListener annotation

**Update :** changing selector to JMSCorrelationID='ID:c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040'" made it work. I tried that a day before, thought didn't work.

```
  @JmsListener(
      destination = "DevQueue01",
      containerFactory = "myContainerFactory",
      selector = "JMSCorrelationID='c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040'"
      )
  public void processInspection(@Valid Inspection bean) {
    System.out.println("In process inspections : \n\n" + bean);
}
```

[image: How correlation id looks in my IBM MQ explorer, kind of hex/EBCDIC]

Comment: Added update for what change made it work

Comment: Maybe you should make the update into an answer and accept it? I assume you have answered your own question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After changing selector to below made it work. I tried that a day before, thought didn't work.
`JMSCorrelationID='ID:c9d5e2d7c5c3e3c9d6d54040404040404040404040404040'"`